# Error creating SAX parser from JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a pdf report with JasperReports but I am getting the following error message in pane:

```
netstjasperrepoits.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
```

the code i had used is :

```
String report="C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\First_Report.jrxml";
JasperReport jr=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,conn);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

Comment: Sir how i remove duplicacy of SAX parser

Comment: you should be able to remove your own question.

Answer (score 0):

after a little investigation I have found the problem and simple solution, download following file or extract it from jasper reports libs folder
xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar
And place it inside your “java.endorsed.dirs” thats all.

Comment: I had applied what you say but still getting same error .

Comment: I fix the problem with the error creating sax parser. You only must put the xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar or xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar at the top in your libraries.
Right click at Libraries --> Properties --> select xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar and move up to the top.