# How to avoid getting the net.Sf.jasperreport.engine.JRRuntimeException:Error creating SAX parser exception?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using *Netbeans IDE 7.3.1* in *Windows 7* I want to print a report using *iReport-5.1.0 plugin* in *NetBeans* but I get this error after click to the Report button:

```
net.Sf.jasperreport.engine.JRRuntimeException:Error creating SAX parser
```

This is the code I am using to print the report,

```
private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\memoire\\report.jrxml");
        String sql = "select * from essai";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jd.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, connect);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: your database conenction is working well? if you post more exception code will be easier.

Comment: @fofo `I get this error after click to the Report button:` - What is it? Is it yours button? Is code you posted related with this button?

Comment: Hi Alex K? Yes my connection is well, this is the error I get net.Sf.jasperreport.engine.JRRuntimeException:Error creating SAX parser, yes the code is related

Comment: Hi ZaoTaoBao?, yes my connection is working well

Comment: @fofo You can look at [JasperReports: Getting JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17715967/876298) & [Error creating SAX parser from JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16005750/876298) posts

Comment: Hi,I'm using what I get to this link this error is gone but I do not see data on the page now I get this error the document has no pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005750/error-creating-sax-parser-from-jasperreports